# Shouldn't Angular 4 ReactiveFormsModule use forRoot pattern?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-reactive-forms

I was reading through a really well written article about Angular's module loading here - https://medium.com/@cyrilletuzi/understanding-angular-modules-ngmodule-and-their-scopes-81e4ed6f7407

Since providers at feature modules' **NgModule** are actually injected globally (and eagerly), the article talks about the "forRoot" pattern used in modules like **RouterModule**.

I came across **ReactiveFormsModule** - https://angular.io/api/forms/ReactiveFormsModule - which has the **FormBuilder** provider, but it doesn't seem to use the forRoot pattern. Doesn't this mean every feature module using ReactiveFormsModule will end up re-creating the **FormBuilder** provider? Am I missing something?

Comment: read the article [Avoiding common confusions with modules in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/avoiding-common-confusions-with-modules-in-angular-ada070e6891f) that expains the `forRoot` usage in depth

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`forRoot` is only relevant for lazy-loaded modules. For eager loaded modules, providers are registered in the application root scope anyway.

If you have imported `ReactiveFormsModule` in lazy loaded modules, then a `FormBuilder` instance per lazy-loaded module would be created.
It doesn't really matter thought, because `FormBuilder` doesn't have a state.
So not being singleton doesn't make a difference for how `FormBuilder` works and because it doesn't have a state, it also doesn't make a difference memory-wise.

Comment: Makes sense. If I understood it right, adding forRoot to ReactiveFormsModule won't affect the behavior either. But for modules with services that have state, lazy loading can make a difference as injection happens at feature module level in that scenario. Pls correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: It definitelly makes a difference if you want a single application-global service instance. Lazy loaded modules introduce a child-scope where they register their service providers, this results in a service instance per lazy loaded module instance and the service won't be available to non-lazy-loaded modules.